# Perl: grep a value in array in array

Tags: perl

How do I grep values from an array of arrays?
My attempt:

```
my $match =grep (/value/, @array);

if ( $match <= 0 ) { ... }
```

I am always getting zero as a output which is incorrect.

I am able to print $value after 2 `for`, loops so I think grep will only work when there is 1 loop.

```
for $value (array) {
    for my $value1 (@$value) 
    { print $value1 };
```

Thanks.

Comment: grep returns a list. If you assign it to a scalar, you will get the length of the list.

Comment: That being said, are you saying that you wish to grep vales from a list of lists?

Comment: Please ignore Len Jaffe's first comment. `grep` does not return a list in scalar context (e.g. when assigning its result to a scalar). It would crash the program if it tried.

Comment: Please ignore Len Jaffe's second comment. There's no such thing as a list of lists. You were correct when you said array of array.

Comment: "Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (locally setting $_ to each element) and returns the list value consisting of those elements for which the expression evaluated to true. In scalar context, returns the number of times the expression was true."   How is that substantially different from what I said?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html#Declaration-and-Access-of-Arrays-of-Arrays - "The simplest two-level data structure to build in Perl is an array of arrays, sometimes casually called a list of lists."

Comment: @ikegami - in lieu of an apology, please make a small donation in my name to the Perl Foundation.

Comment: @Len Jaffe, Because each operator decides what it [returns](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=347416) in scalar context. It's not always going to be number of scalars it would have returned in scalar context. Countless people have been confused by the claim you made.

Comment: @ikegami - Except in grep's case, it is the list of values that evaluated to true, or the number of them in a scalar context, which is equivalent to the length of the list. So you're batting zero at contradicting me in this thread.  Maybe you should take a moment before you tell somebody to ignore somebody else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To grep first level of arrays into `@result`

```
my @result = grep { grep { /search/ } @$_ } @array;
```

grepping final strings into `@result`,

```
my @result = grep { /search/ } map { @$_ } @array;
```

Comment: Thanks , so shall I use second level answer as I am looking for answer in 0 or 1 ..Like if I grep something and if value is blank then I shouldn't process. if (@result)  { found value } else { array is empty }... I am correct